# Slow upload with .csv files and PHP

Tags: php, performance, mongodb, csv, file-upload

I've created a function to upload csv files using PHP and insert its contents into a Mongo database.

The upload is taking to much time to be completed and I don't have idea how to build a better code to do this.

Bellow my function in PHP:

```
public function importEmail($file,$list_name,$header){

    $data = $this->ReadCSV($file, $has_header);        
    global $Email;
    $falhas = 0;

    array_shift($data);

    if($data === false) {
        return false;
    } else {                  
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $Email->email = $value[$header["email"]];
            $Email->first_name = $value[$header["fName"]];
            $Email->last_name = $value[$header["lName"]];
            $Email->gender = strtoupper($value[$header["gender"]]);
            $Email->status = $value[$header["status"]] !="" ? $value[$header["status"]] : "1";
            $Email->list_name = $list_name;
            $Email->opt_out = $v = (strtoupper($value[$header["opt"]]) != "" ? strtoupper($value[$header["opt"]]) : "N");               

           if(!$Email->update(trim($value[$header["email"]]))) $falhas++;              
        }   

      }      

        return $falhas === 0 ? true : false;
}
```

***EDITED***
This is the update() method which is responsible to insert records into MongoDB

```
public function update($id) {
    global $mongo, $gClient;

    $update = array(
        '$set' => array(
            'userData.name' => $this->first_name,
            'userData.lastName' => $this->last_name,
            'userData.gender' => $this->gender,
            'userData.optOut' => $this->opt_out == "Y" || $this->opt_out == "N" ? $this->opt_out : "Y",
            'userData.lastUpdate' => (int)(microtime(true) * 1000),
            'userData.status' => $this->status == 0 || $this->status == 1 ? +$this->status : 0
        ),
        '$setOnInsert' => array(
            'userData.registerDate' => (int)(microtime(true) * 1000)
        )
    );

    if(is_string($this->list_name) && strlen($this->list_name) > 0)
        $update['$push'] = array(
            'userData.meta' => array(
                'type' => 'listname',
                'name' => $this->list_name
            )
        );

    $result = $mongo->{$gClient->slug}->usersHistory->update(array(
        'userEmail' => $id
    ), $update, array(
        'upsert' => true
    ));

    if(!$this->email) $this->email = $id;

    $mongo->{$gClient->slug}->usersHistory->update(array(
        'userEmail' => $id
    ), array(
        '$set' => array(
            'userEmail' => $this->email
        )
    ));

    return $result['n'] > 0;
}
```

Those .csv files are always bigger than 50k (lines).

How can I build something faster than this method?

Comment: You say in your questions it's the upload that's taking too long but you gave us the code for the data processing section. Which part is slow, how do you know, and what else have you tried?

Comment: The update() method is responsible  for insert into Mongodb.

Comment: So the upload function is taking too long? If that's the case, where is the code for that method and what have you done to narrow down where the issue is, specifically? IE: How do you know that it's the file upload and not the insert into your MongoDB?

Comment: @the_pete Question updated with update() method.